# How to check if my firewall is actually protecting me?

Tags: firewall

I have set up a home firewall inside a virtual machine and I have configured it. How can I test if it is actually working and blocking dangerous connections coming from the internet? Are there some specific tests than I can run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following site [Shields up](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) this should give you a good indication of you firewall setup

Comment: you might want to include some information about what services Shields Up provides. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have not advised the software you are using, but if you are using Linux, you can run the command

```
iptables -vnL
```

Which will show you which rules (including number of bytes and number of packets) have matched.

Also, you have not advised what resources you have access to, or what you are trying to connect, but if you have access to another PC, you may well be able to run tests from the remote PC and see if the firewall is working as expected, for example, telnetting to the IP and port of a service which you know is active but blocked.